# Как обрезать картинку

Tags: delphi, изображения

Есть изображение размером 50 на 50 пикселей. Необходимо сделать из него круг обрезав все лишнее или же сделать все лишнее белым цветом.

Размер круга - вписанная окружность в квадрат 50 на 50 пикселей.

Например, было

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

стало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Содаете белый битмап с черным кругом, а потом вызываете `Win32Check(BitBlt(LBmp1.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, LRect.Width, LRect.Height, LBmp2.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCPAINT));`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov что за самодеятельность в чужом вопросе? Если вы хотите дать хороший ответ на "свой" вопрос, то пожалуйста запостите свой вопрос и свой ответ - думаю многие плюсанут.

Comment: @Kromster И давно на SO запретили редактировать чужие вопросы?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov у вас явно есть ответ и вы хотите переоткрыть вопрос чтобы его запостить. Повторюсь - лучше запостите свой вопрос и свой ответ, а этот низкокачественный вопрос пускай канет в небытие. Ни к чему поощрять ТС который явно не прикладывает никакого труда.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, случае (и без оптимизаций):

1. Загрузить картинку в память;
2. Пройтись по всем пикселям, проверяя, расположены они внутри или снаружи круга - проверяется по расстоянию от центра картинки до проверяемого пикселя;
3. Присвоить нужным пикселям новый цвет;
4. Сохранить картинку.

Если будут дальнейшие затруднения - уточните в чем.

Comment: `BitBlt(...., SRCPAINT)`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov загадочно .. вот только чтобы получить круг, надо его сначала тоже как-то сгенерить/сделать

Comment: попиксельно если закрашивать, то края рваные будут

Comment: @teran верно. Рассчитать процент закраски не сложно, и это тоже относится к деталям и "оптимизациям".

Comment: ‘Canvas.Ellipse(...)‘

Comment: эх. не успел коммент про `ellipse()` вставить пока доки читал :)